# How to form a string using variadic templates without recursion in c++ 11

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

```
template <typename ...Args>
void logImpl(tloglevel level, Args&& ...args)
{
    ostringstream stream;
    (stream << ... << std::forward<Args>(args)) << '\n';
    syslog(level, stream.str());
}

func A()
{
int a =10;
std::string b = "test";
logImpl(LOG_INFO, "printing",a,b);
}

func B()
{
unsigned long t = 6700;
logImpl(LOG_INFO, t);
}
```

I understand that we can achieve it using variadic templates. But is it possible to do it without recursion? fold expression is not an option as only c++ 11 is supported. Please let me know if anyone else has better idea using variadic templates without recursion or fold expression. I want to do it in c++11.

Comment: I don't understand what the expected behavior is. Perhaps it'd be clearer if you implement it using recursion and/or fold expressions and put that in the question, but mention that you would like to do it without recursion in C++11?

Comment: You should clarify what do you want to get. A function taking variadic arguments and returning concatenated string ? `makeString("abc",10)` should return `ala10` as std::string?

Comment: I want to write a function which takes  loglevel and variadic arguments and that function should form a string with variadic arguments. Then i want to call syslog passing this log level and string.

Comment: By *should form a string* you mean all arguments are concatenated to string?

Comment: yes, all the arguments should be concatenated to string, i have updated the original post

Comment: You can get string from ostringstream by `.str()` and then call `c_str()` to pass const char to syslog invocation: `syslog(level, stream.str().c_str());` Ahh, my bad it uses fold expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion to make this work.

You can create fake array with expanding parameters pack when filling it:

```
template<class ... Args>
std::string makeString(Args...args){
    std::string s;
    int temp[] = { (s += toString(args),0)... }; // concatenation
    static_cast<void>(temp);
    return s;
}
```

for `toString` you provide overloads for handling all types you want.

For example:

```
template<class T>
std::string toString(T t){
    return std::to_string(t);   // for numbers 
}

std::string toString(const std::string& str){
    return str;
}

std::string toString(const char* str){
    return str;
}
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xJ2hHg)

---

Hmm, you don't even use `toString`, version with `ostringstream` is:

```
template<class ... Args>
std::string makeString(Args&&...args){
    std::ostringstream os;
    int temp[] = { ((os << std::forward<Args>(args)),0)... };
    static_cast<void>(temp);
    return os.str();
}
```